# call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() and addCategoryFilter() on null after upgrading Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 below filters are not working.

```
  protected function _getProductCollection() {
                return $this->getProducts();
            }

            public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();
         $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
    $collection = clone $this->_collection;
    //$collection = clone $this->_collection;
    $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(Select::WHERE)->reset(Select::ORDER)->reset(Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(Select::GROUP);

    if(!$category_id) {
        $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id);
         $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                            ->addFinalPrice()
                            ->addTaxPercents()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sw_featured', [1], 'left')
                            ->addCategoryFilter($category);
        }
 $collection->getSelect()
            ->order('rand()')
            ->limit($count);

        return $collection;
        }
```

The above code is worked Magento 2.1.x, but after upgrading it's not working.

Please suggest to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the right product collection then  `addAttributeToFilter()` and `addCategoryFilter()`  should be worked. I have checked two od method, do not see anyone is deprecated.

I guess that issue at  `$collection` variable,from  where `$collection` comming at `getProducts()`.

**see below code:**

```
$count = $this->getProductCount();

 $collection->addMinimalPrice()
```

how you getting `$collection` variable value?. $collection is undefined variable. at your code

### Update

You have inject product resource collection class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` for getting Product collection

So,you need to modify  at `__construct()` at your class:

In below example, I assume that you do not have `__construct()` ,So `__construct()` look like.

```
/**
 * Product collection factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
     parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    );
}
```

After that, you need to  product collection by replace `$collection = clone $this->_collection;` by

```
/** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
```

**getProducts() look like **

```
public function getProducts() {
    $count = $this->getProductCount();
    $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");


    if (!$category_id) {
        $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id);
    $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sw_featured', 1)
            ->addCategoryFilter($category);

    $collection->getSelect()
            ->order('rand()')
            ->limit($count);

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: See my thread updated. I'm getting the collection by extending `ListProduct` core file.

Comment: As you use clear() method `$collection->clear()`  then $collection  is goes to emty then use  of `addAttributeToFilter` and other is not worth.

Comment: what your requirement?

Comment: get the product collection by filtering custom attribute (`sw_featured`) equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure flat catalog is not turned on. This usually happen when that is the case.